# Why do my fractions in java print out as 1.0?

Tags: java, double, fractions

I want my variable i to have the value of these fractions depending on a random number. However, when I print out i, it displays 1.0.
Why is that and how can I solve this issue?

```
public class Musik{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Interval();
    System.out.println(Interval());
  }
  public static double Interval(){
    int a = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
    System.out.println(a);
    double i = 0;
    switch (a) {
      case 0 : 
        i = 2;
        break;
      case 1 : 
        i = 3/2;
        break;
      case 2 : 
        i = 4/3;
        break;
      case 3 : 
        i = 5/4;
        break;
      case 4 : 
        i = 9/8;
        break;        
    }
    return i;    
  }
}
```

Comment: *Integer division* effect: when we divide `int` to `int` (say `9` to `8`) the result will be `int` as well (`1`); put it as `9.0 / 8.0` (please, note `.0`)

Answer (score 2):

Because `3/2` is a division between two integers with the outcome of `1`. You probably want to divide the two doubles `3.0/2.0` with the outcome of `1.5`

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting result with decimal precision, add `d` to your denominator

Ex:

`5/3` returns `1`

But

`5/3d` returns `1.6666666666666667`